# How can I CSS animation change to jquery animate() code?

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-mobile

I'm a student form South Korea studying coding jquery mobile. and i want to make mobile web app! I was making some slot machine animation with starting shaking motion. And I made it by CSS code. But for starting this animation, I had to use 'js'. So, I want to change (jquery animate code) from this "css"

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var myShakeEvent = new Shake({
threshold: 15
});
myShakeEvent.start();
window.addEventListener('shake', shakeEventDidOccur, false);
function shakeEventDidOccur () {
$('#lot').animate({

~~~here i want to input the animation.~~

}, 5000, function() {

});
}
};
```

~~~ and this is css animation.~~

```
<div data-role="main" class="lot">
<div id="a"></div>
<div id="b"></div>
<div id="c"></div>
</div>


<style>
*{ padding: 38px;
margin:1px;
overflow: hidden;
}                               
.lot{
max-height: 880px;
max-width: 270px;

}
#a { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b1.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
#b { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b2.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground2 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
#c { 
background-size:contain;
background-image: url(b3.jpg);
background-position: top;
background-repeat:repeat-x;    
animation: animatedBackground3 5s ease;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-direction: alternate;
}   
@keyframes animatedBackground {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: 5000px 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground2 {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: -5000% 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground3 {
from { background-position: 0 0; }
50% { background-position: 4000% 0; }
to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS animation and jQuery animation is 2 different thing.

Since you already have CSS animation keyframes defined, all you need to do is just apply the `animation` property.

Assuming that `shakeEventDidOccur` is the function to jump start or apply the animation.

Notice that the `animation` property is shifted to a separate CSS block where when `.lot` has the class `.startAnimation`, each of the block will now have the `animation` property, in which will start the animation.

```js
function shakeEventDidOccur () {
  $('#lot').addClass('startAnimation');
}
```

```css
#a { 
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(b1.jpg);
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}   
#b { 
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(b2.jpg);
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}   
#c { 
  background-size: contain;
  background-image: url(b3.jpg);
  background-position: top;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}   
@keyframes animatedBackground {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 5000px 0; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground2 {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: -5000% 0; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
}
@keyframes animatedBackground3 {
  from { background-position: 0 0; }
  50% { background-position: 4000% 0; }
  to { background-position: 0 0; }
}

.lot.startAnimation #a {
  animation: animatedBackground 5s ease;
}
.lot.startAnimation #b {
  animation: animatedBackground2 5s ease;
}
.lot.startAnimation #c {
  animation: animatedBackground3 5s ease;
}
```